# org.apache.jasper.JasperException in struts1

Tags: struts

**struts-config.xml**

```xml
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/index.jsp" name="HelloWorldActionForm" 
            path="/HelloWorld" scope="session" type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp"/>
    </action>
    <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
```

**helloWorld.jsp**

```xml
<%@taglib uri= "/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld"prefix="bean" %>

<html>
  <body>
    <bean:write name="HelloWorldActionForm" property="message" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The exception I am getting is:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /helloWorld.jsp (line: 4, column: 54) 
 The JSP  specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace
```

I am unable to understand why the exception is coming.

Comment: To me, it seems like debugging an issue in `helloWorld.jsp` would be a lot easier if we had any idea what was in `helloWorld.jsp`.

Comment: i have add hello world.jsp file details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a space before the word "prefix", like the error message indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in catalina.properties file located at TOMCAT INSTALLED DIRECTORY OR FILES

1. GOTO Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\catalina.properties
2. JUST ADD SPECIFIED LINE BELOW IN CATALINA.PROPERTIES FILE

org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE=false

After Adding This just Restart the Server

THIS WORKS FOR ME

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the jasperException is came it is related to jsp page only. Mainly it is occuered by the jsp syntax problems

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the below tag Duplications.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

It will remove that error.